# Joomla : Urls redirections not functioning with ids in IE (like /listen#playlist_jingle)

Tags: internet-explorer, url, hash, joomla, redirect

EDIT : It is the url redirections that doesn't work. I am under Joomla 1.7 and the redirections doesn't work either in IE9.

All my urls are redirected like this :

```
mydomain.com/listen -> mydomain.com/fr/listen
```

Now I want :

```
mydomain.com/listen#blabla -> mydomain.com/fr/listen#blabla
```

And I get it on FF, Google Chrome, but on every versions of IE (even 9) I get :

```
mydomain.com/listen#blabla -> mydomain.com/fr/listen
```

---

I have a Jplayer & Jplayer_playlists page. When I click on specific IDs (actually, buttons made with `<a>` tag), it activates a javascript function to make a new playlist.
Also, I have added the code below for these playlists to be accessible via a `/listen#playlist_gregorian` -like url.

This works, but not on IE8 : IE8 removes the hash (like `#playlist_gregorian` here).

I am working in Joomla (maybe that it is a Joomla problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you've been to the old addresses previously in IE and so the page content is cached? When you return to the page you don't ask the server for the page - so don't get the redirect.

If so - clearing the browser cache/history (remember 301 redirects are cached/stored by the browser) should solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried... It did not make something. The hash is removed after the redirection.